# How can i point the url www.test.com on port 123 for ssl to a sub site under the default website?

Tags: ssl, web, iis

I have a default website under iis10.
Under the default webaite i have 2 sites running.
- site1
- site2
My ssl certificate is added to the bindings at port 123 .
 The ur is by example www.test.com
I want to reach site1 with www.test.com:123
And site two with port 80. I dont want that site 1 gets the url www.test.com:123/site1 I want to reach it by the short Url.

How can I make this work?

Url rewrite?

I tried to make url rewrite but never had experience with it before.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems you want to access the www.test.com:123/site1 by using www.test.com:123 url.

If this is your requirement, I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>

            <rule name="RewritetoSite1">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.test.com:123/site1/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```